# How to deserialize an JSON object with an array, without knowing the types of objects in that array

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7

I'm building a Foursquare app for Windows Phone 7. It's working nicely with HttpWebRequests and I'm receiving JSON objects perfectly. I'm using the DataContractJsonSerializer(type) method. But when deserializing this JSON to the object I want, It all goes well until I there's and array of objects, where I don't know which object-type to expect (also don't know the amount & order of objects). But I do need to define this type when deserializing in the method DataContractJsonSerializer(type).

Let me show you a snapshot of JSON which causes the trouble:

```
notifications":
[{
    "type":"notificationTray",
    "item":{
        "unreadCount":0
    }
},{
    "type":"message",
    "item":{
        "message":"OK! We've got you @ Strandslag 4. You've been here 2 times."
    }
}]
```

So I'm deserializing this to an array of Notification objects, with two memers: "public String type" and an "public Object item". I can't know which, and how many, Notification's there will be in the array (and thus of what type the 'item' member must be). As you can see in the JSON, the first notification has an item of type int, but the second notification's item is of type string. But I need to know that for the deserialization... Or else it just stays null.. So I cant cast it to the correct type..

Does anyone knows how to solve this nicely?

Comment: Look here for information about building of 4th & Mayor (another Foursquare app). It can be helpful for you: http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2011/03/4am-leaderboard-notification/

Comment: Thanks Ku6opr! That sure is an option for my problem. Need to rebuild my app from the standard Deserialize method, to the library used in the example. I'm gonna try it! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm not 100% sure this will answer your question but can you not use javascript to convert whatever the object is into a string and then manipulate it that way?

Something like:

var value = whatever[number].toString;

This would give you a string you can work with. You could then try to parse it back to an int.

var valueInt = parseInt(value);

Then use an IF statement to see if the valueInt exists or not to determine what kind of value the first object has.

Comment: That could also be a solution, but I'll first try the JSON.net library special for Windows Phone. I personally think that would give me some more cleaner code. Thanks for your help!